# sql server divident is not getting proper result

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

i am working on windows application, i have a code in vb.net like this:

```
PT1 = PT - LT
 If PT1 > modvAL Then
 q1 = PT1 / modvAL
 Else
 q1 = 1
End If
```

here my PT1 value is 2752 and ModvAL is 1440 then i am getting my q1 value is 2 (this is my vb.net code)

```
 set @PT1=@PT-@LT
if @PT1>@modvAL
  begin
  set @q1=@PT1 / 1440
 else
  begin
  set @q1=1
  end
```

this is my stored procedure part ,here am doing same thing in sql server but my q1 is not getting proper value? what is wrong with my stored procedure

Comment: What should be the expected value ??

Comment: i have to get q1 is 2 in the stored procedrure also.code am getting correct .but in sql am getting 1

Comment: Why does the stored procedure have the magic value of 1440 instead of using `@modVal`?

Comment: What are the datatypes of the variables in SQL? If they are all `INT` you will get lots of rounding.

Comment: my @q1 variable is integer

Comment: my all variable is integer data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `INT` datatype, the results will all be rounded. Take the following examples:

```
DECLARE @floatValue FLOAT = 100
DECLARE @intValue INT = 100
DECLARE @divisor INT = 90

SELECT @intValue / @divisor  -- this will return 1
SELECT @floatValue / @divisor -- this will return 1.11
```

So to fix your query, you could make the data types of your variables `FLOAT` (or another non-integer numeric type) instead.

Comment: here i am getting 1.95 ,i want to convert that to 2

Comment: i want to round to positive side

Comment: Then [ROUND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175003.aspx) the final value like this `ROUND(@result, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

warning: this is a wild guess because your question lacks basic info (example data, data type of involved fields, expected result).

i suppose you are performing the calculation sql side relying upon approximate datatype fields hence the result is not the actual result but the nearest value supported by the datatype.

should you will to share proper information it would be possible to understand if this is the issue and find a solution.

[here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/29/sql-server-difference-and-explanation-among-decimal-float-and-numeric/) you can find some info about approximate data type in sql server; also check on [ms documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing 'end' of if block.

```
set @PT1=@PT-@LT
if @PT1>@modvAL
  begin
     set @q1=@PT1 / 1440
  end //missing
else
  begin
     set @q1=1
  end
```

Also with single statements you can use if-else without blocks.

```
set @PT1=@PT-@LT
if (@PT1>@modvAL)
     set @q1=@PT1 / 1440
else
     set @q1=1
```